# Setting recyclerview/cardview background colour dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-viewholder, android-background

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the background colour of each recycler view item if the item contains a certain word. For example, my custom item contains 4 textviews and 1 checkbox, I want the background colour to be light brown if the item contains the word "dead", red if it contains "bench".. ect ect.. is there a way to do this?

Here is my item.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp" >


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Squat"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtExercise"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="%"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtPercentage"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtReps"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtReps"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Reps"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtReps"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtWeight"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtWeight"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Weight"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/check1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/check1"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my recycler view:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Workout> workout;
SharedPreferences prefs;
int firstSecondOrThird;


public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout, int thePosition) {
    mContext = context;
    this.workout = workout;
    this.firstSecondOrThird = thePosition;
}
// INITIALIZE HOLDER
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

//BIND DATA TO VIEWS
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    final Workout isCheck = workout.get(position);
    holder.check1.setChecked(isCheck.isCheck1());
    prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("checkstate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
    isCheck.setCheck1(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));

    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            isCheck.setCheck1(isChecked);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, isChecked).apply();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return workout.size();
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the base `ViewHolder` class, `itemView` is public, so in your `onBindViewHolder()` method you check for which color you want and set it.

```
    int colorResId = R.color.default;
    if (workout.get(position).getExercise().contains("bench") {
        colorResId = R.color.red;
    //  more tests for which color to use
    }
    int color = getResources.getColor(colorResId, context);
    ((CardView) holder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: To add to this you can add another field to your `Workout` class. Something like `int workOutColor` create the getter and setter and then in the code you can just do `holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(workout.get(position).getWorkOutColor());`

This is much cleaner and makes your class do the logic.

Comment: Thanks, this does work good, unfortunately when I use it, it basically gets rid of the cardview attributes, the corners are no longer curved ect. Is there any way around this?

Comment: It also seems like the colours keep changing lol.. sometimes I run the app and its working properly.. other times it'll change the colours to colours that aren't anywhere in my app?

Comment: Oh yeah, there's a bug with color resources, I updated my answer to show you how to work around it.

Comment: getResources won't work, it says it cant be resolved

Comment: fixed by changing getResources to ContextCompat.getColor

Comment: That worked for getting the colours to cooperate, still cuts the corners from cardview though :(

Comment: Updated answer, see if that helps the corners.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!! Just had to take out the new ColorDrawable part as well:
((CardView) holder.itemView).setCardBackgroundColor(color);

Comment: what if i want to change color of background outside the viewholder, i.e color of recyclerview itself but dynamic for every item

Comment: @SiddarthG Call `setBackgroundColor` on the `RecyclerView` to change the overall color.  If you want to change the color of an item, change a property that will affect your item's background color, then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.  In `onBindViewHolder`, check the property and change the background color.  If this isn't clear, please post a new question with your relevant code for the entire community to look at.

Answer (score 1):

So your ViewHolder has a `View` associated with it. Which is inflated with the xml file that you posted. Now in your `onBindViewHolder` method you bind your data to your `MyViewHolder`. You can get the `View` of the `MyViewHolder` by calling `holder.itemView` which returns a `View` object.

```
View itemView = holder.itemView;
```

Now from here you can get references to your `TextView`, `Button` etc by calling `findViewById` on `itemView`

So for example if you had a `TextView` in your xml file with an id `android:id="@+id\myTextView` you can do the following in your `onBindViewHolder`,

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //..... Other stuff
    View itemView = holder.itemView;
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myTextView.setBackgroundResource(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
   //...... Other stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve a problem in RecyclerView and came across your answer above.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas for me for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739404/android-recyclerview-how-do-i-programmtically-select-textview-background-color