# android recyclerview: how do I programmatically select TextView background color?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews.  On each CardView, the user previosuly selected the "type" from a dropdown dialog.  The type choices are "Work" and "Home".  The type choice is stored in an SQLite database as a String.  When I run the app, no view is shown for the TextView "cardtype1" which is supposed to show the type choice from the database.

How can I set a different background color for TextView type that is shown on the CardView, depending on what the user selects and is stored in the database?  Below is the partial code from the Adapter file.

```
Adapter.java
...

public List<ListItem> listItems;

private static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView cardType1;

    private ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardType1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardType1);

public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = (ItemHolder) holder;        

    itemHolder.cardType1.setText(listItem.getType());

    if (listItem.getType() == "Work") {
        itemHolder.cardType1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    else if (listItem.getType() == "Home") {
        itemHolder.cardType1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008080"));
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code, you didn't see the back ground or what ? please provide what `listItem` contain it's already carry position.

Comment: Correct, no background color is shown.

Comment: it's seems your problem with `listItem`, please log it for test purpose.

Comment: meaning use log.d?  how?

Comment: I am using Android Studio.  Error message "Cannot resolve method 'd(java.lang.String)'

Comment: The log output for the types is correct.  Both "Home" and "Work" show up in the logCat.  So there must be something wrong with the "==" part or the itemHolder line.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

when user click on the option, update the required object in the list, `listItems`. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in your adapter.

Comment: The object is updated correctly and the type is correctly saved in the SQLite database in another Activity.   The problem I am having is I am trying to access the type from the database using getType() so that I can test what the user selected.  If the user selected "Work" I want the TextView (on the CardView) in the ViewHolder of the RecyclerView to show one color.  If the user selected "Home" then the TextView would show another color.  I hope I am describing this well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to set the textColor when user selects from your two option.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = (ItemHolder) holder;        
    itemHolder.cardType1.setText(listItem.getType());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    if (listItem.getType() == "Work") {
       itemHolder.cardType1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
    else if (listItem.getType() == "Home") {
       itemHolder.cardType1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008080"));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the user selects the "type" on another Activity and then clicks a "Save" button that saves the type in the database and then displays the RecyclerView list.  I want the ViewHolder to show different background colors for a TextView depending on what "type" was saved.  So I don't need a ClickListener.  I just want the View to update with a color and the color depends on the type that was saved in the database.